# django-social auth Exception Type: AuthAlreadyAssociated how to redirect custom

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

Trying to add social auth with my django website. All is done can log-in/sign up. But getting only one problem while trying to sign-up with already existed social account it's redirecting me to a exception page(Exception Type: AuthAlreadyAssociated) but i want the user to redirect on a page where i want. How ?

Comment: show some code to clarify your question

Comment: My code is okay. Just want to add some more for redirecting user if they are trying to add already added social account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the purpose for the [Exception Middleware](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#exceptions-middleware), you need to extend it to set the needed URL to redirect to.